# certain setup.exe files will not run

Tags: windows-7

I am experiencing a similar problem, to a post i was reading on here, certain setup.exe installer programs will not run, though they show in task manager as "not responding" I believe system restore would prob fix this issue, but the earlist restore point I have is well after this problem arose and thus it has no effect..could this be a problem with .msi? or the instal shield wizard? As I say it seems to be happening only with some limited install .exe the others have no problem
Should i install/update dirx and Net.framework?..are these actions likely to help?..can I find an error log for the non responsive setup.exe files?, if so where?, I have already tried resetting the registry
The daft thing is that the same program using a different installer  setup.exe works with no problems

Windows 7 professional X64   Sp1

Comment: Did you try contacting the producer of said files?

Comment: Seems likely the problem is in the program, not anything on your computer. Your user TEMP folder would be the likely place for any created log files.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, it's possible that *failing to create a required System Restore Point* prevents installation. Check if that is an issue: In Control Panel, Recovery, select *Configure System Restore* to see how much space is available and to add more if needed.
[image: System Restore Point Management]

An MSI installer might be set to create a Restore point, while the EXE version might not require it.

BTW, when possible, I prefer to simply open up minor updates in a tool such as 7-Zip and copy the files to a temporary location, check them in [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/), and then move them to the proper location. It's often faster than using an installer.